# Filter DataGrid with any of the Textboxes that has input

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, textbox

The scenario was there should be any or multiple `TextBox` that is not empty and display it on the `DataGridView`.

I think my SQL is incorrect.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Command1 As New OleDbCommand

    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim sql1 As String

    Try
        Dim cnn3 = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=StudentInfoSysDB.accdb;")
        cnn3.Open()
        If txtID.Text <> "" OrElse txtLastN.Text <> "" OrElse txtFirstN.Text <> "" OrElse txtMiddleN.Text <> "" OrElse txtCourse.Text <> "" OrElse txtYear.Text <> "" OrElse txtGender.Text <> "" OrElse txtSection.Text <> "" Then

            sql1 = "Select * from Students Where([ID],[LastName],[FirstName],[MiddleName],[Course],[Year],[Gender],[Section]) VALUES('" & txtID.Text & "','" & txtLastN.Text & "','" & txtFirstN.Text & "','" & txtMiddleN.Text & "','" & txtCourse.Text & "','" & txtYear.Text & "','" & txtGender.Text & "','" & txtSection.Text & "')"
            Command1 = New OleDbCommand(sql1, cnn3)
            i2 = Command1.ExecuteNonQuery
            MessageBox.Show("Searching Done!")
            ds.Clear()
            Refresh()
            cnn3.Close()
        Else
            MsgBox("Please Input Atleast 1 Field")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not replace your original question with a new one based on an answer. Edit the question by adding an update instead or leave a comment at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. Your `SELECT` statement is wrong. The `SQL SELECT` syntax is:

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

**Never concatenate user input with application SQL to form the SQL sent to the database** in order to avoid [**SQL Injection attacks**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). The easy way to do this is to use parameterised statements. Parameterised statements are where the variable parts of the SQL are replaced with markers (usually ?). I

You should do something like this in order to populate a `DataGridView` with the results.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=StudentInfoSysDB.accdb;)

     Try

        Connection.Open()

        Dim SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE ID = ? OR  FirstName = ? OR  MiddleName= ? " & _
                       " OR LastName = ? OR Course = ? OR  Year = ? OR  Gender = ? OR Section = ?"

        Dim sqlcommand As New OleDbCommand
        With sqlcommand
            .CommandText = SQlQuery
            .Connection = Connection
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtID.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txtFirstN.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txtMiddleN.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txtLastN.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", txtCourse.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtYear.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", txtGender.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", txtSection.Text)
        End With

        Dim ds As New DataSet

        Dim Adapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcommand)

        Adapter.Fill(ds)

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        SQLConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

         MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```

**NOTE:** The above code does not combine fields to make a search. It will look for any record that matches with the input of any textbox

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Should be `Dim Adapter As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcommand)`. Edited

Comment: Data type mismatch in criteria expression
"ERROR HIGHLIGHTED ON Adapter.Fill(ds1)"

Comment: is ok now just changed the autonumber to text THANKS